# Lead/Contact Duplication Rule - Not to check NULL values

Tags: acumatica

I have configured duplicate validation settings for lead and contact with the following options:
1. Matching Field = First Name; Score Weight = 1, Transform. Rule =None; 
2. Matching Field = Last Name; Score Weight = 2, Transform. Rule =None; 
3. Score Threshold for Lead and Contact = 3;
4. Validate Lead and Contacts for Duplicates on Entry = TRUE

When I am adding new Leads with empty First Name and with same Last Name, it shows that the record is possible duplicate.
Is it possible to not to check NULL values during the Lead/Contact Validation?

Comment: What have you setup in Acumatica that checks for the duplicate? is this a setup for lead/contract or are you using code such as PXCheckUnique?

Comment: I'm using Lead/Contact Valudation Rules from CR101000 (Duplicate Validation Settings tab)